# How can I convert the hex color to CSS3 filter options in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, colors

I have the hex color (i.e. `#ff0000`). I want it to use on CSS3 filter options as hue saturation and brightness. I can use JavaScript, but don't know how can I convert it to this.

I mean I'll convert it to RGB, than HSL and than CSS3 filter options(hue-rotate, saturation and brightness)

Comment: I mean Hex to RGB, RGB to HSL and at least HSL to CSS3 filter options

Answer (score 1):

I found this one:
https://gist.github.com/barretts/e90d7e5251f36b183c67e02ba54c9ae1

You can try serveral times to get the best results.